# Precision in double

Tags: java

I've got problem with precision in java. I have to calculate:

```
a * b -c, where:
a = 5.454E14
b = 3.646E-40
c = 2.3
```

The score is `-2.3`. How I can solve it? 
I don't want  to round up the score.

Comment: Something like BigDecimal should be helpful.

Comment: What relationship does (should) the score have with `a`, `b` and `c`?

Comment: @KevinDTimm, I don't think it would; if the values a, b and c are only known to four sig figs, attempting to display the 25-odd sig figs the OP appears to be expecting isn't going to help much; most of the digits beyond the -2.3 he has will be junk anyway.

Comment: 5.4E14*3.6E-40 is about 1.5E-25... Just for curiosity, what do these values mean that even a value so low cannot be rounded?

Comment: @Brian - I suspect you're correct, I see now that he has a HUGE number multiplied by a phenomenally TINY number, which is going to result in another really TINY number.  The math here is 'rather' irrelevant, though, in his domain, Matthew may not think so.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BigDecimal` which offers a configurable precision.

Answer (score 0):

use `Big Decimal` for precision calculations